# Popover view shows up after it has been dismissed /why two segue being fired at the same time

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, xcode4.2, uipopovercontroller

I am new to xcode and I have been running to this problem and I am not sure how to fix it.  My Issue is I have UIViewController that has a combination of popover segue, custom segue and a navigation controller.
The user clicks on a text box and the pop over shows up, and they are able to select  a city form the pop over and the pop over is dismissed.  But if they click on a button that performs the custom segue way the pop up shows up again.

Is there any way I could stop the pop from firing again?

Here is how my code is

```
@interface ….
{
    UIPopoverController *popoverController; 
}
@property (strong) UIPopoverController *popoverController;

@end
@implementation …

@synthesize popoverController;


…
-(BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    return YES;
}

-(void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    self.popoverController = nil;
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *storePopeOver;
    UIPopoverController *thePopover;
    UIViewController *ContentVC;

    if(self.popoverController)
    {
        [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];
        self.popoverController = nil;
    }
    //Popover 
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"FindFrom"])
    {

        storePopeOver =(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue;
        thePopover = [storePopeOver popoverController];
        self.popoverController = thePopover;
        [segue.destinationViewController setDelegate:self];
        self.segueTyp = @"FROM";  

    }
//Custom segue
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"TimeTable"])
    {
        [segue.destinationViewController setDelegate:self];
    }
}

//When the user clicks on the  textField performDegue
- (IBAction)FromTxtFieldBeginEdit:(UITextField *)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"FindFlightsFrom" sender:self];
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you created the segues did you Ctrl+drag from the button?
I like to drag from the VC, that way they are neer called automatically and you have to call performSegueWithIdentifier for a segue to happen.

Comment: Darren,  I am using text boxes and I did do Ctrl+drag.  The Issue I have is the pop shows up and it gets dismissed when they select Item from the table view, but the issue I have is if after the selection the use wants to go to another page the pop up shows up again.  I don't understand why this is happening but I will try your way to see if that makes any difference.